# Delete Empty list and Null at the same time

Tags: list-manipulation

Here is the code.

```
Table[If[a > 0 && d > 0 && 
    4 (1000 a + 100 b + 10 c + d) == (1000 d + 100 c + 10 b + a),
   {a, b, c, d}, Unevaluated[Sequence[]]],
  {a, 0, 9}, {b, 0, 9}, {c, 0, 9}, {d, 0, 9}] /. {} -> Sequence[]
```

However, this is not working.

```
DeleteCases[
 Table[If[a > 0 && d > 0 && 
    4 (1000 a + 100 b + 10 c + d) == (1000 d + 100 c + 10 b + a),
   {a, b, c, d}],
  {a, 0, 9}, {b, 0, 9}, {c, 0, 9}, {d, 0, 9}], Null]
```

This is not working either.

```
Table[If[a > 0 && d > 0 && 
    4 (1000 a + 100 b + 10 c + d) == (1000 d + 100 c + 10 b + a),
   {a, b, c, d}, Unevaluated[Sequence[]]],
  {a, 0, 9}, {b, 0, 9}, {c, 0, 9}, {d, 0, 9}] //. {x_List} :> x
```

None of these works.

Comment: try `Table[....] //. {} ->Sequence[]` or `Table[....] //. {} ->Nothing`?

Comment: @kglr How about `Null`? Any better solution?

Comment: `Table[...]//. Null | {} -> Nothing`?